# Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined Array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having an array `customerList: Array<String> = [];` and a function which pushes the value from server into this array. It's working fine except when i use `.filter()` on this array it gives me undefined error.
This code is:

```
customerList: Array<String> = [];

ngOnInit() {
this.customerService.getCustomers().subscribe(res => {
    this.customers = res;
    for (const cust of res) {
      this.customerList.push(cust.first_name);
    }
  }
);
}

findChoices(searchText: string) {
return this.customerList.filter(item =>
  item.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
  ); 
 );
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<mwl-text-input-autocomplete-container>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_name" name="customer_name" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                 placeholder="Customer name" formControlName="customer_name" mwlTextInputAutocomplete
                 [findChoices]="findChoices"
                 [getChoiceLabel]="getChoiceLabel" autofocus>
</mwl-text-input-autocomplete-container>
```

The `customerList.filter()` in `findChoices()` is giving the error.

P.S.- I'm using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-text-input-autocomplete)

Comment: Can you add `console.log(this.customerList)` to the start of `findChoices`, and add the output to this question please?

Comment: @user184994 it's undefined there, but on ngonInit() it is displaying the data

Comment: Where are you calling `findChoices` from? Can you add that code as well please?

Comment: @user184994 added

Comment: Okay, and if you `console.log(this)` from inside that function, does it print the name of your component?

Comment: @user184994 if i'm using a dummy data list inside the `findChoices` it works but it is not working with the `customerList`

Comment: can you please post the whole component code

Comment: So if you `console.log(this)` what is printed? We need to find out whether the issue relates to calling context, or whether something is setting `customerList` to undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are passing function object `findChoices` as value to `[findChoices]`, the value of `this` will not be bound to your component, and hence `this.customerList` will be undefined.

You can make use of closure to ensure `customerList` is visible to `[findChoices]` by following below steps:

1. Change `findChoices` implementation to return a function that can be used as value of `[findChoices]` - that is a function that accepts a string parameter.

   ```
   findChoicesIn(list) {
     return (searchText) => 
             list.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()));
   };
   ```
2. Use the function thus generated as value of `[findChoices]`

   ```
   [findChoices]="findChoicesIn(customerList)"
   ```

Comment: Working!! Thanks

Comment: Fine Tanks Wand!

Answer (score 0):

Seams your **`customerList`**  is empty or null, just add a check

```
if(this.customerList && this.customerList.length > 0){
  return this.customerList.filter(item =>
  item.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
  ); 
}
```

Comment: it is still undefined.

Comment: you need to pass the search filter

Comment: @Sajeetharan Actually OP is passing a reference to the function, not invoking the function

Comment: @user184994 yeah right! it cant be undefined once it holds the value

Comment: @Sajeetharan how to pass the search filter?

Comment: You don't need to. If you pass a reference to the function then `mwlTextInputAutocomplete` will pass in the search filter